# Creating threads memory issue

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a button that when clicked calls `sendFile()` to send a file to a server. In the function I am creating a thread, then sending the file in the thread. My question is what happens to the thread after the file is sent? Will the old threads continue to run as I create more threads?

```
void sendFile(File f) {
    Thread mythread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             // code to send the file
         }
    }           

    mythread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/threads/states.html)

> A thread can die in two ways: either from natural causes, or by being
>   killed (stopped). A thread dies naturally when its run method exits
>   normally. For example, the while loop in this method is a finite
>   loop--it will iterate 100 times and then exit. public void run() {
>       int i = 0;
>       while (i < 100) {
>           i++;
>           System.out.println("i = " + i);
>       } } A thread with this run method dies naturally after the loop and the run method complete.

So when run finishes the thread would die i.e stop !!